# asks the user to input a sentence and outputs the number of times the word 'the' occurs in it

Tags: python

How can I write a python that ask a user for a sentence and print how many time was "the" used in the sentence.
This is the code that I tried

```
string1=str(input("Enter a sentence"))  
splitstring= string1.split()
list1=[]
for word in splitstring:
    if word== 'the':
        list1.append(word)
lengthstring= len(list1)
print("The number of times the word the occurs in the string is ", lengthstring)
```

Comment: simply do splitstring.count('the')

Comment: Why are you doing `if word== 'beach'`? Don't you want to test for "the"?

Comment: What about the word ‘then’, should that count as containing ‘the’?

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what do you get instead? (An error, your computer shuts down, it only answers with "42" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works but you could just count how many times element occurred in list with count() like so:

```
string1 = input("Enter a sentence: ")
splitstring = string1.split()

print("The number of times the word the occurs in the string is ", splitstring.count('the'))
```